# Using ansible, in playbook, replace spaces in file with newlines?

Tags: ansible

Say I have a file named 'text.txt' and I want to replace all the spaces with newlines?  How does one do this?  Say, for text.txt... "This is a test" and I want it to be changed to:

```
This
is
a
test
```

So I tried...

```
- name: Format Command Line
    replace:
      path: /text.txt
      regexp: " "
      replace: "\n"
```

But that does not work, I just get "\n" literally for each space.  I read somewhere I need to double escape the '\', so I tried '\\\\n' but that did not work either.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Duhe... "\\n" Does the trick.